# Django {% extends 'base.html' %} {% block content %} {% load static %} does not work, nothing works actually

Tags: python, django

I have a html template i want to code in django.
For now i need to take the header and footer parts and make images, css and js into static files.
I tried to do it but it does not quite work, can anyone help me with it? I would greatly appreciate if someone can fix my mistakes and send me the file

{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block content %} {% load static %} none of them work

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Please include your code inside the Question. It's impossible to help you with just "It does not work, please help", isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the HTML file to base.html.js or make sure that the template directory is configured correctly in settings.py

for reference
TEMPLATES = [

```
'DIRS' = [os.path.join(base_directory, 'template_directory')]
```

]

Answer (score 0):

Hi ai ohto for {% load static %} read this Django documentation:
[documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/)

or in short add this to your project settings.py file:

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS=[
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'YourDjangoAppName/YourStaticFolderName'),
]
```

for {% extends 'base.html' %} {% block content %} you have to provide more information. Its better to add your code to your question.